# T-SQL Parse XML Column Problems

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

This is what the column xml looks like

```
<Attributes>
    <ProductAttribute ID="9">
        <ProductAttributeValue>
            <Value>21</Value>
        </ProductAttributeValue>
    </ProductAttribute>
    <ProductAttribute ID="10">
        <ProductAttributeValue>
            <Value>25</Value>
        </ProductAttributeValue>
    </ProductAttribute>
</Attributes>
```

And i want to return it like

```
ProductAttribute        ProductAttributeValue
--------------------------------------------------
9                       21
10                      25
```

My query now looks like this

```
SELECT
    ProductId as ProductId, 
    ProductAttributeNode.value('(@ID)', 'int') as ProductAttributeMappingId,
    ProductAttributeNode.value('(//ProductAttributeValue[1]/Value/text())[1]', 'int') as ProductAttributeValueId
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        ProductId,
        CAST(AttributesXml as XML) as AttributesXml,
        Sku
    FROM
        ProductAttributeCombination
) AS PAC
CROSS APPLY AttributesXml.nodes('//Attributes/ProductAttribute') as T1(ProductAttributeNode)
```

And what i get back is

```
ProductAttribute        ProductAttributeValue
--------------------------------------------------
9                       21
10                      21 <--- not 25
```

Comment: Just some background: `//` is a *deep search** finding each and any node with the given name. The XML will be the *whole lot*, but - coming out of nodes - with a *relative position*. That's why you can reach to a parent node with `..`. The given answer is correct and would work even without the `./`. Your `<ProductAttributeValue>` is right below the *current node*.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `//` in the value method, everytime it looks from the first `ProductAttribute` element I guess. When you know the parent elements you don't need `//`

```
ProductAttributeNode.value('(//ProductAttributeValue[1]/Value/text())[1]', 'int')
```

should be

```
ProductAttributeNode.value('(./ProductAttributeValue[1]/Value)[1]', 'int')
```

Comment: @Brakke in this case it would be nice to accept the answer.